# change background color with javascript if we click on the field

Tags: javascript, html, web

if we have in my page index.html :

```
 <span class="token-label" style="max-width: 1072px;">Hello world</span>
 <span class="token-label" style="max-width: 1072px;">Bye world</span>
```

in the page, we have a form that contains fields :

```
Hello world    Bye world
```

i want to : when i clik on one of this two fields i will get a small list below : lit of 3 colors and i choose a color to color the background of this field with this color , in javascript please

i am a beginner in javascript, i don t know how we can do this, please help, i just tried to get a value of "Hello world" like this :

```
document.getElementsByClassName('token-label')[0].textContent
```

i search on the internet and i find : container toggle tag with color...
but i dont understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the most simple solution in vanilla javascript should look like the snippet bellow

did I understood your question well?

```js
// obtain elements
const htmlCollection = document.getElementsByClassName("token-label");
const array = [...htmlCollection];

// add listener to show the palette
array.forEach(span => span.addEventListener("click", modifyColor, false));

function modifyColor(mouseEvent) {
    const target = mouseEvent.currentTarget;
    const x = mouseEvent.clientX;
    const y = mouseEvent.clientY;

    function colorChosen(color) {
        target.style.backgroundColor = color;
    }

    showPalette({ x, y }, colorChosen);
}

function createDiv(style) {
    const div = document.createElement("div");
    Object.entries(style)
        .forEach(([property, value]) => div.style[property] = value);
    return div;
}

function showPalette({ x, y }, callback) {
    // palette itself
    const paletteElement =
        createDiv({
            position: "absolute",
            left: `${x}px`,
            top: `${y}px`
        });
    document.body.append(paletteElement);

    // here you can redefine html colors
    const colors = ["LightSalmon", "LightGreen", "LightBlue"];

    // each color creation and adding click listeners
    colors.forEach(colorValue => {
        const colorElement = createDiv({
            width: "40px",
            height: "20px",
            backgroundColor: colorValue
        });
        colorElement.addEventListener("click", () => {
            cleanup();
            callback(colorValue);
        }, false);
        paletteElement.append(colorElement);
    });

    // don't forget to remove palette from document
    function cleanup() {
        document.body.removeChild(paletteElement);
    }
}
```

```html
<span class="token-label" style="max-width: 1072px;">Hello world</span>
<span class="token-label" style="max-width: 1072px;">Bye world</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can provide a script, it works for me so it should work.

```
#token-label {
  background-color: ; /* Set your background color */
}
```

javascript:

```
 var colors = ["#"]; // Set the background color you want to change
var colorIndex = 0;
function changeColor() {
    var col = document.getElementById("token-label");          
    if( colorIndex >= colors.length ) {
        colorIndex = 0;
    }
    if (colors[colorIndex] == col.getAttribute("currentColor")){
        col.style.backgroundColor = null;
        col.setAttribute("currentColor",col.style.backgroundColor);
      }
        else {
        col.style.backgroundColor = colors[colorIndex];
        col.setAttribute("currentColor",colors[colorIndex]);
      }
    
    colorIndex++;   
}
```

And change `class="token-label"` to `id="token-label"` Let me know if it works if not maybe I got something wrong so I can change it.